# Bootstrap - Navbar size settings

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a site based on the 3-col-portfolio Bootstrap template (http://startbootstrap.com/templates/3-col-portfolio.html).

I need to apply a reasonably large nav menu along the top of the page - therefore I would like the navbar to collapse at 992px rather than 768px - being reasonably new to Bootstrap I don't really understand how to do this without hacking / overriding the media query declarations in the main bootstrap.css - is there an easier way that I'm missing - or is this the solution!?

Comment: You will have to override media query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize bootstrap right online at http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#variables-basics. Just fill in 992px for '@grid-float-breakpoint' and press download. No manual building needed.